# Route MS 2007 excel file in

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-office-2007, routing

Can the MS excel 2007 file also be routed in outlook just like the way it used to be in 203 [link text](http://www.towson.edu/adminfinance/ots/training/documentation/Word%202003/Word_Routing_Documents.pdf)
I was not able to find the option in fil>send

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, Microsoft has removed this feature from Office 2007. Too bad.